# inserting UIColletionView as subview causes it to disappear and cellForItemAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, ios8

I have a UICollectionview added to the view of a UIViewController through storyboard.

I have another UIVIew called ControlPanelView also added to the same main view.

In code, I reposition this UICollectionview  to be a subview of ControlPanelView.

On iOS 7 its been working just fine.

On iOS 8, suddenly its just not working. The UICollectionview disappears completely, and cellForItemAtIndexPath isn't even called!

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I ended up just creating the UICollectionView in code and adding it as a subview, instead of using storyboard. For whatever reason, that solved the problem ... not sure why or how, but now its working.